# Sluggish animations on new install

Tags: gnome, performance, animations

I recently installed Ubuntu (18.04.4 - GNOME 3.28.2) on a partition of my SSD on my Windows 10 laptop (Huawei Matebook X Pro -- i7-8550U @1.80GHz X 8, 16 gigs Ram). I'm enjoying it so far except for one thing: pretty much every animation is extremely sluggish. For example, the animation for Show Applications happens over about 5 or fewer distinct frames. Swiping between workspaces isn't a lot better. Hitting the superkey to bring up a view of all running apps is even worse, maybe 2 frames, and typing to search for an application from this screen is really laggy too. So while generally everything feels about as performant as Windows 10 (gaming notwithstanding -- I haven't tried to game on it nor do I plan to), the animations lead the overall experience to feel like I'm on a really old machine, which is unfortunate.

How can I fix this? I've heard that gnome is maybe the slowest flavor, but I'm not sure. I've installed a few minor cosmetic extensions, like blyr, but the problem seems to persist even when I disable them, and it doesn't seem like they should be causing such drastic problems anyway considering that the hardware I'm running this on isn't exactly poor, even for a laptop.

I have a dedicated nvidia GPU on this laptop, but it doesn't seem to recognize it. I probably need to install drivers for it. I don't know if that's the first move to take to fix it, though I would prefer to stick to the intel dedicated graphics if I can to preserve battery life.

Comment: Same here, but even on desktop (RTX 2070, Ryzen 5) with clean Debian 10 and Gnome, no extensions, mods, etc. All animations are really slow and with low FPS. Just to compare, Windows 10 is blazing fast on this rig.